# How can I run a python script for a certain amount of time, pause it, determine where in the code it is at, and then continue it?

Tags: python

I've looked into the code module, but I don't see the kind of functionality I need there. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you allowed to modify the module which you want to inspect?

Comment: Are you working in any particular IDE?  To me this sounds like a great candidate for Eclipse with PyDev and it's Debugger capabilities so that you can set Break Points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. Is it possible to automate what I want to do with pdb? My question was incomplete - I would like to script this operation.

Comment: Well we have no idea what you want to do.

Comment: You can ask a new specific question incoporating what you've learned from this answer. Make sure to mark this answer as accepted if you do.